# Solve recurence relation $T(n) = 5T(n-1) + n^{\sqrt n}$

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

I need to solve the recurence relation:

$$T(n) = 5T(n-1) + n^{\sqrt n}$$

I am trying to solve it, but it can't be done by any methods I know (Master theorem and etc.)$
Any tips?

Comment: It can be explicitly written as $T(n)=5^n(T(0)+\sum_{i=1}^n 5^{-i}i^{\sqrt{i}})$, not sure if more can be done (maybe some asymptotics)

Comment: Are you interested in the asymptotics?

Comment: yes. And i assume that $T(0) = \Theta (1) $

Answer (score 2):

As Sil said, your "closed-form" expression is
$$T(n)=5^n \left( T(0) + \sum_{k=1}^n 5^{-k} k^{\sqrt{k}} \right) = 5^n \left( T(0) + \sum_{k=1}^\infty 5^{-k} k^{\sqrt{k}} - \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty 5^{-k} k^{\sqrt{k}} \right) \, .$$
You can then estimate $$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty 5^{-k} k^{\sqrt{k}} \leq \int_{n}^\infty 5^{-k} k^{\sqrt{k}} \, {\rm d}k = \int_{n}^\infty e^{\sqrt{k}\log(k) - k \log(5)} \, {\rm d}k = \int_{n}^\infty e^{-k\log(5) \left(1-\frac{\log(k)}{\sqrt{k}\log(5)}\right)} \, {\rm d}k \, ,$$
and you will find that $$1-\frac{\log(k)}{\sqrt{k}\log(5)}$$
has a unique minimum at $k=e^2$ and so
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty 5^{-k} k^{\sqrt{k}} \leq \int_n^\infty e^{-k\left(\log(5)-2/e\right)} \, {\rm d}k = O\left(e^{-n\left(\log(5)-2/e\right)}\right) \, .$$
I doubt you will find closed form for your constant $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 5^{-k} k^{\sqrt{k}} = 0.406435769... \, .$$

Comment: A rather good approximation for the last number is $$\frac{2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt[4]{3}+\sqrt[4]{7}}{10 \sqrt[4]{3}}$$ which is in a absolute error of $3.47 \times 10^{-8}$

Comment: How did you come up with it?

Comment: Just looking in the ISC. Cheers. (I shall pass the number to one of my former PhD students who enjoys this kind of problem)

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html

Comment: $\frac{2}{5}+\frac{7^{2/3} \left(16+2^{2/3}\right)}{10000}$ gives an error of  $1.76 \times 10^{-9}$

Comment: Have you kept searching the ISC?^^

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici hi, you told me that you know the answer to my recent question. can you look into that, please?

Comment: @4444. Done in a lazy manner. Cheers :-)

Comment: $$\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{14} + \frac{1}{598} + \frac{1}{615801} + \frac{1}{600856887410}$$
gives an absolute error of $9.2\cdot 10^{-25}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the recurrence relation is linear, we can write $T(n)=T_h(n)+T_p(n)$.
The homogenous solution is given by $T_h(n)=T(0)5^{n-1}$. Writing $n^{\sqrt{n}}=5^{\frac{\log(n)}{\log(5)}\sqrt n}$ it is clear that $T_h(n)\gg n^{\sqrt n}$ for $n\gg1$ since $n \gg \sqrt{n}\log(n)$ in this regime. It follows that to leading order $T(n)=T_h(n)+o(5^{n-1})$. This is the principle of dominated balance.

Comment: It should be $T_h(n)=T(0)5^n$?